# Submit a form when page loads - struts 2

Tags: javascript, forms, struts2, form-submit

I want to submit a s:form when page loads.
here is my code :

```
<s:form id="login_form" action="" method="post">
<s:textfield label="User name" id="login_form_username"
            name="username" value="abc.xyz" cssClass="txtbox"
            required="true" />
        <s:password label="Password" id="login_form_password" name="password"
            value="pass" cssClass="txtbox" required="true" />
        <s:submit value="Login" />
    </s:form>
```

Actually as shown in above code, I will set uname and pwd dynamically and then want to submit this form directly using javascript.

I tried this :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
      document.forms.login_form.submit();
</script>
```

but had no success.

Please help...
Thanks..

Comment: What happened? Anything in the JavaScript console? What does the form name/id render as? If you already know the values, is doing it this way even necessary?

Comment: Have you checked out the javascript error console? If there are not errors, maybe you are not placing your javascript snippet in the correct place on the page. Try either somewhere at the end of `<body>` or maybe even in `<body onload="document.forms.login_form.submit();">`.

Comment: I don't know the values already but as I specified, I will later on set these uname and pwd values in jsp page itself from the requesting page before loading page. I just want to bypass login process as I will be passing uname and pwd by some another way.

Comment: @rodion 
+1 for putting `script at the end of <body> ` It was failed earlier since uname and pwd fields didn't get their values set when page was loaded so every time, those fields were `null`. I set their values within script and now it is working... Thanks again to All...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<s:form id="login_form" action="" method="post">
```

As you can see the action to which the form will be submitted is missing. How will the above javascript know on which action to submit this form to. 
Try filling in a action name.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Jquery code:

```
document.ready(function(){
  $("#login_form").submit();
});
```

dont forget to specify action attribute of form.

Note: to use jquery you need to add jquery library.

Answer (score 0):

**document.forms.login_form.submit()** throwing undefined error.instead of that you can use 
**document.forms[0].submit()**

you can use onload attribute for page loads works

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function submit(){
      document.forms[0].submit();
    }
</script>

  <body onload="submit()">
  <s:form id="login_form" action="" method="post">
       <s:textfield label="User name" id="login_form_username"
            name="username" value="abc.xyz" cssClass="txtbox"
            required="true" />
        <s:password label="Password" id="login_form_password" name="password"
            value="pass" cssClass="txtbox" required="true" />
        <s:submit value="Login" />
    </s:form>

 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit  through java script means you have to give code like this eg:

If your from name is ***login_form*** in java script then you can give like this

```
function submitform()
{
    document.forms["login_form"].submit();
}


<s:form id="login_form" name="login_form" action="your action name" method="post">
<s:textfield label="User name" id="login_form_username"
            name="username" value="abc.xyz" cssClass="txtbox"
            required="true" />
        <s:password label="Password" id="login_form_password" name="password"
            value="pass" cssClass="txtbox" required="true" />
        <s:submit value="Login" onClick="submitform()"/>
</s:form>
```

Here you should remember 2 important points:

> 1)without action name it will not work because, for going to the
>   struts.xml you need action name right in your code i didn't see the action name.
>
> 2)Secondly, in your code you written some java script code but, you not
>   called that function name either through submit button nor through
>   body onload function. I will assume like for posting purpose you did
>   this coding k that is not the problem.

what i was showed above code that is one way. Another way is without submit button your code should run means, you can type like this in a jsp page

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="1;URL=youractionname.action">
```

you have to write this code before body only then your jsp page works like what you want.

Here i used for both the codes ***action name(youractionname)*** means without action name in struts2 page won't go to the action class

> Bottom Line:Action name is important in struts2